# Replacing values in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
"group1": [{"key1": "AAA", "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'": "BBB", "key3": "CCC", "key4": "DDD"},
            {"key1": "EEE", "key3": "FFF", "key4": "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'", "key4": "HHH"},
             {"key1": "AAA", "key3": "BBB", "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'": "JJJ", "key4": "III"}]
```

How would I quickly and easily run through it all and replace all values of "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID" with something like "User_ID"?

Focus is on speed and resources, as these may be long list with many dictionary values .

Answer (score 2):

What about the following?

```
# Dictionaries with "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'" in both keys and values:
group1 = [{"key1": "AAA", "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'": "BBB", "key3": "CCC", "key4": "DDD"},
          {"key1": "EEE", "key3": "FFF", "key4": "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'", "key4": "HHH"},
          {"key1": "AAA", "key3": "BBB", "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'": "JJJ", "key4": "III"}]

for group_dict in group1:

    # Fast key replacement (no test in for loop):
    try:
        group_dict['User_ID'] = group_dict.pop("\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'")
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # Value replacement:
    for (key, value) in group_dict.iteritems():
        if value == "\xef\xbb\xbfUser_ID'":
            group_dict[key] = 'User_ID'

print group1  # Cleaned up dictionaries
```

yields

```
[{'key3': 'CCC', 'key1': 'AAA', 'User_ID': 'BBB', 'key4': 'DDD'},
 {'key3': 'FFF', 'key1': 'EEE', 'key4': 'HHH'},
 {'key3': 'BBB', 'key1': 'AAA', 'User_ID': 'JJJ', 'key4': 'III'}]
```

This does not use much memory (beyond the memory for the new `"User_ID"` string), and I can't think of anything faster.

Note that your second dictionary has two "key4" keys, which is strange (dictionary have keys that are unique).

Comment: I am unable to change the keys from the above code.After googling got to know that keys cannot be replaced.Is it right ???

Comment: Dictionary keys can be "replaced", but only by creating a new key and deleting the old one. This is what is done in the above code. This code works as given with Python 2 (it gives the result printed at the end). Are you using Python 3? What do you obtain instead?